# Phonegap/Cordova Social sharing js shareViaFacebook not working in window phone

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have used [SocialSharing.js](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin for share link in my phonegap app(**Window Phone**). Some function working and some not. I cannot share link direct on facebook. Example are below:-

Working:-

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, null, 'http://www.x-services.nl')">link only</button>
```

Not working:-

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('Message via Facebook', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">Direct Fb link</button>
 //when click on 'Direct Fb lin' button, it show error message i.e, Invalid action.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because, this plugin doesn't support shareViaFacebook method on windows phone platform.

The available methods on WP8 are: available, canShareViaEmail, share, shareViaEmail and shareViaSMS.

[Link to documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#4b-usage-on-windows-phone)

Comment: so, what is alternative way to achieve `shareViaFacebook` method

Comment: If when calling method .share() there is no facebook choice, then you can write own plugin, because support of existing plugins is bad for WP :( i hope useful [article](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2013/02/15/creating-phonegap-plugins-for-windows-phone-8.aspx) you can read about it.